# VSCode with Python, execute command prior to venv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv, pyvenv

Due to company constraints I cannot immediately execute PowerShell commands:

```
File C:...Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170
```

The workaround I already found (thanks Stack!) is to execute, in the command line (not as a PS script):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process
```

This solves the problem and when I'm running code for real, it works well.  When I am in the middle of a development/debugging session in VS Code, however, this command does not execute.

Is there a place in one of the JSON setup files where I can pre-execute the above command before PS or cmd or the python debugger attempts to run `Activate.ps1`?  This fixes venv problems for me and anyone else with problematic corporate script execution policies.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code supports adding `tasks.json` files to set up automatic tasks.

**A simple example:**

```json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "test",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "dir",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": true,
                "clear": false
            },
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

*This setting is to run the `dir` command to read the files in the directory when opening the folder.*

[image]

**How to create a `task.json` file?**

1. Open command palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Search and select **Tasks:Configure Task**

   [image: configure task]
3. Choose **Create task.json file fromtemplate**

   [image: creshhssshsshfhate]
4. Choose **Others**

   [image]

*More about `tasks.json`:* [Click here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks)

***PS:***

Regarding debugging, the `launch.json` file can also help a lot. Click [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) to know more.

Comment: Thank you, that's very likely the right track for this.  In and of itself this cannot solve the problem, because the command executed from tasks.json executes in a separate process from the terminal (PowerShell) process, and the present scope of the executed command is per-process.  By changing "-Scope Process" to "-Scope CurrentUser" I massively increase the security threat area but also solve the problem.

If there is a way to execute a task *inside of a new terminal instance, when the instance is started*, that would actually solve the problem safely.